# captutar eventos de un inputDialog en java

Tags: java

tengo un inputDialog pero quisiera saber si se le pudiera agregar eventos a dicho dialogo ya que no quiero que ingrese letras y que al presionar una letra simplemente no la escriba solo tengo esto

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad a llevar: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Puedes explicarte mejor ?

> 'al presionar una letra simplemente no la escriba'

Para Java hay una librería llamada JavaFX que mediante programas como Scene Builder, te permite asociar de forma gráfica un método con eventos como 'onclick' , etc. Podrías usar esto para meter tú *input dialog* en un método asociado a un evento .

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de un KeyEvent, un evento del teclado, agrega una condición, donde hagas el llamado al KeyEvent y lo compares con el tipo de dato de la variable donde se tiene que guardar el dato.